# PayPal REST API not returning payment_info

Tags: paypal

I am using the REST API to authorize a PayPal transaction, and when it returns to confirm & execute the payment, I'd like to retrieve & display payer information such as name, address, phone, etc from their PayPal account for a checkout order confirmation page. (To avoid them having to type in all their billing/shipping address info, since this should be available from PayPal.)

Currently the return is only showing this for payer:

```
PayPal\Api\Payment Object
(
    [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PPModel:private] => Array
        (
            [id] => PAY-2EC51985XH550123JKHG3C4Y
            [create_time] => 2013-06-28T15:53:23Z
            [update_time] => 2013-06-28T15:53:23Z
            [state] => created
            [intent] => sale
            [payer] => PayPal\Api\Payer Object
                (
                    [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PPModel:private] => Array
                        (
                            [payment_method] => paypal
                        )

                )

            [transactions] => Array
            ...
```

The documentation states:

### payer_info object

- This object is pre-filled by PayPal when the payment_method is paypal.

(see https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#payerinfo-object)

Even after the payment is executed, I still receive no payer_info object from PayPal. I am wondering if PayPal is only returning the info I prepopulate before sending the user off to PayPal? e.g.:

```
$payer = new Payer();
$payer->setPayment_method('paypal');
```

Is there a way to retrieve the user's name/address/phone/etc (what I expected to be available from `Payment::get($pay_id)->getPayer()->getPayerInfo()->getShipping_address()`) using the REST API?

Or do I have to have the user duplicate their efforts and enter address information on my checkout page? I sure hope not, as this is one of the big advantages of using PayPal as a payment method.

Comment: Perhaps this is exactly what Express Checkout is for? Or maybe REST API just isn't there yet?

Comment: The "payer_info" should return the buyer information after you Execute the payment. The full write out you provided doesn't have a "payer_info" category. I'm going to research that further now. 

The REST stuff is still very new and incomplete in some ways - capturing buyer information before the execute is one of them. But we are introducing new features for it often. 

The classic API calls have it all figured out and work well.

Comment: I looked up the Express Checkout token (EC-76L38216UH578922K) and noticed that an Execute never occurred. I wasn't able to find a transaction ID or a failure for this attempt.

Comment: So REST will eventually behave like Express Checkout, returning all the buyer information before execution? Is there any idea of when that behavior will be available? Or should I switch to using the classic API for now?

Comment: We do have an internal plan for the feature roll out for REST but I can't go into detail on it. I would recommend using the Classic APIs for Express Checkout - especially if you need to capture buyer information before the payment completes. Sorry.

Comment: Fwiw, I scrapped using the REST API after much wasted work and went with the Express Checkout API, which worked fine.

Answer (score 6):

I thought I would post an answer in case anyone else has this issue.

It does appear that the REST API fails to return the shipping information the majority of the time. Especially when using the `GET /payments/payment` endpoint. However I have seen it return shipping information from the `POST /payments/payment/<PAYMENT_ID>/execute` endpoint before.

Anyway, following the comments above it looks as if the OP ditched the REST API and went back to Express Checkout. Which is fair enough if you want to get the shipping data up front.

However, if you use the PayPal IPN in conjunction with the REST API it will provide the shipping and billing info on the callback. So you could collect the information at that point.

The only problem I see with doing this is that you can't confirm the address is correct with the user. PayPal however does show this information to the user as they make their way through payment and allows them to change it if necessary. So I believe it's safe to assume the data is accurate.

Comment: Yeah, I needed to display address before confirming payment, and Express Checkout ended up working fine for my needs. Surprised that nearly a year later, the REST API still doesn't offer this. Seems like pretty basic functionality.

Comment: Having this same exact issue now in August.